# Asking per-site permission before exposing extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, permissions

I have a chrome extensions (that includes a native client) which I would like to expose only if the user authorizes it (once) for a given site. Is there some built-in mechanism with a standard user interaction for this IMO fairly common use case or do I have to roll my own with a content script that asks permissions and stores them in localStorage, as it currently seems?

Comment: Do you mean like [optional permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions)?

Comment: I want to have a "Do you want to allow xtension X on site example.com" pop up on first use on the upper side of the screen and have "this time only/always/cancel" options. The content script is already set to run on all sites and the only permission currently necessary is nativeClient. I'm alright  on the permissions front but would like to shield the extension from all arbitrary websites that don't have user's permission.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're aiming at. Which API permission do you need? Since you're already injecting a content script everywhere, it sounds more like an honor system.

Comment: Ya, it sounds like you you are looking for a library to manage the enablement of the features on sites not so much the chrome permissions to access the sites.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "activeTab" permission:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab
And in your Chrome extension code create an URL check system, so when you visited a new URL (from that tab.id) Then it shows a popup dialog with OK and Cancel.

Example:

```
var x;
if (confirm("Press a button!") == true) {
    x = "You pressed OK!";
} else {
    x = "You pressed Cancel!";
}
```